# diff-utility and ftp

Tags: linux

It seems that diff displays differences in identical files. The right one was transfered via ftp, the left is local. Timestamps changed. Is is possible, that's that the only reason for differences?

chris

Answer (score 0):

One reason this can happen is because of line-difference or other whitespace differences.  Have you tried doing a `diff -b`?  `ftp` can actually introduce whitespace differences as a convenience so the file will conform to the expectations of the local operating system (unless you set the file transfer mode to "binary").  You could also use `cmp` to check if the files really are different at a binary level, or `od` to print out the binary content....

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed whitespace only! I found an option to ignore whitespace in "Meld".